# My event does not trigger when expected

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, events

My Custom TextBox:

```
class NameTextBox
{
    public string nameid {get; set;}
}
```

My Main Class:

```
class PanelPopulator    
{        
    public NameTextBox nameTextBox = new NameTextBox();

    public PanelPopulator()
    {
        nameTextBox.MouseClick += NameTextBox_MouseClick;
        p.Controls.Add(nameTextBox);
    }

    private void NameTextBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Button)
        {
            case MouseButtons.Left:
                // Left click
                break;

            case MouseButtons.Right:
                //Right click        
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is my `NameTextBox_MouseClick(...)` event does not seem to trigger on a mouse click. I tried the same thing on a normal form and it works fine.

Comment: show complete implementation of custom textbox?

Comment: what is `p`? and could you please format your indentations?

Comment: please post a minimal compilable example, this would not compile

Answer (score 1):

`NameTextBox` is just a regular class from what you have in your code. In order for it to be a custom textbox it probably needs to inherit from a regular `TextBox` class?